# iOS SBJson request goes bad

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, sbjson

I'm trying to parse a JSON feed from my wordpress blog. I've got a custom field I need to use but can't get it to work with SBJson. Here's how my feed looks like (I've stripped the other useless stuff):

```
{
   "status":"ok",
   "count":27,
   "count_total":2552,
   "pages":95,
   "posts":[
      {
         "id":8978,
         "type":"post",



       "custom_fields":{

        "btnNameScrollBlog":[
           "<null>"
        ]
        "author-name":[
           "John Doe"
        ]
     },
}
```

I'm trying to get the author's name.
Here's the code I used for getting the feed on iOS:

```
-(void)downloadRecentPostJson{

    [recentPost removeAllObjects];
    [previous_total_per_page removeAllObjects];


    NSURL *urls = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/?json=%@",url,methodJson]];
    NSData *sa = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urls];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:sa encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSDictionary *result = [jsonString JSONValue];
    NSArray* posts = [result objectForKey:@"posts"];
    total_page = [[result objectForKey:@"pages"] intValue];
    total_post_per_page = [[result objectForKey:@"count"] intValue];

    [previous_total_per_page addObject:[result objectForKey:@"count"]];

    current_page = 1;

    for (NSDictionary *post in posts) {
        id custom = [post objectForKey:@"custom_fields"];
        id thumbnail = [post objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
        NSString *featuredImage = @"";
        if (thumbnail != [NSNull null])
        {
            featuredImage = (NSString *)thumbnail;
        }
        else
        {
            featuredImage = @"0";
        }





        [recentPost addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[post objectForKey:@"id"],[post objectForKey:@"title_plain"],[post objectForKey:@"excerpt"],featuredImage,[post objectForKey:@"content"],[post objectForKey:@"date"],[post objectForKey:@"comments"],[post objectForKey:@"comment_status"],[post objectForKey:@"scrollBlogTemplate"],[post objectForKey:@"url"],[post objectForKey:@"specialBtn"],[post objectForKey:@"btnNameScrollBlog"],[post objectForKey:@"latScrollBlog"],[post objectForKey:@"longScrollBlog"],[post objectForKey:@"openWebUrlScrollBlog"],[post objectForKey:@"gallery"], [custom objectForKey:@"author-name"], nil]];

    }
```

I tried setting the custom_fields object as an id:  id custom = [post objectForKey:@"custom_fields"];

And then using it to get to the author's name:  [custom objectForKey:@"author-name"]

But I get an NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector  error.

Any suggestions??

What if I try and get the category title from the post?

```
  "categories": [
                {
                    "id": 360,
                    "slug": "deals",
                    "title": "Deals",
                    "description": "",
                    "parent": 0,
                    "post_count": 28
                }
            ],
```

Do I put the categories in an array like this? How do I get the title from that? I tried this and getting the object at index 3, but got an error.

```
   NSArray *cat = [post objectForKey:@"categories"];
```

Comment: The error message means that "author-name" is an NSArray but the code is treating it as if it was an NSString.

Comment: Your Json is not formatted right, try using http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'-[__NSArrayM rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector error.` means that you are treating an array as a string. Your code is nearly correct, you just need to get the first item from the array (preferably with a check that the array isn't empty) because

```
"author-name":[
     "John Doe"
]
```

is an array containing one string. So:

```
NSArray *names = [custom objectForKey:@"author-name"];
NSString *name = [names firstObject];
```

---

```
NSArray *categories = [custom objectForKey:@"categories"];
NSDictionary *category = [categories firstObject];
NSString *title = [category objectForKey:@"title"];
```

Comment: Could you help me with the category title as well? I got confused.

Comment: Where is it nested at? Again, it contains an array so you need to index into the array to get the dictionary and they use the key.

Comment: It's nested in the posts. Each post has a category

Comment: Updated answer. Break your code into lines. Log each part if you get confused (the class and the contents).